# Função para retornar os níveis de um objeto em Javascript

Tags: javascript, lógica

Estou criando um app com AngularJS onde preciso fazer um "mapeamento" da estrutura de pastas do sistema, assim quando for necessário fazer alguma mudança na estrutura eu mudo apenas este arquivo e não todo o sistema.

Para fazer isso, eu pensei em montar uma **.config** que retornaria um objeto com todos os diretórios do meu app. A estrutura de diretórios é algo desse tipo:

```
app/
|- controllers/
   |- cad/
|- directives/
|- views/
```

O problema é que se eu for escrever diretório por diretório ainda não fica funcional então pensei que poderia criar um objeto com a estrutura multi-nível e então retornar outro objeto já com os diretórios montados, algo do tipo:

```
var path = {          
  app: {              
    controllers:{     
      cad: ""         
    },                
    directives: "",   
    views:""          
  }                   
}
```

Então a partir dessa variável eu retornaria um objeto com todos os "mapeamentos" disponíveis com base no objeto, assim:

```
return {
  app:{
    _: "app/"
    controllers: {
      _: "app/controllers/",
      cad: "app/controllers/cad/"
    },
    directives: {
      _:"app/directives/"
    },
    views: {
      _:"app/views/"
    }
  }
}
```

O problema é que não estou conseguindo pensar em como fazer essa função para que ele entre em todos os níveis e monte essa estrutura. Alguém tem algum materia de funções recursivas ou alguma solução?

Comment: o que tu queres fazer é algo que leia a file-structure e a passe para um objecto ? Se sim, e estiveres a usar node, podes fazer isso com o `fs.readdir` em que cada pasta é pushed para o objecto sendo que o valor dessa chave é o full-path do mesmo. 

O truque aqui é fazer a recursividade para o caso de teres N pastas dentro das pastas, mas não é rocket science :)

Comment: é algo semelhante a isso mas não uso o node. meu app é sobre o Cordova e para manter um padrão de projeto eu preciso desse tipo de controle

Comment: Está certo que eu só pesquisei "Cordova readdir" mas apanhei um link mesmo bacano que te pode ajudar na tua quest - [mesmo que só um bocadinho](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/create-file-explorer-in-blackberry-phonegap-project/)

Comment: Uma key value não bastaria?

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você está usando Windows, você pode utilizar um batch file para gerar um JSON representando sua estrutura de diretórios:

```
dir2json.bat [diretório] >[arquivo destino]
```

Exemplo:

```
dir2json.bat . >lista.json
```

> dir2json.bat

```
@echo off &setlocal

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if "%~1"=="" (set "root=.") else set "root=%~1"
set "pre0=                                    "

pushd %root%
echo([
call:dirtree "%CD%" "1" "1"
popd
echo(]
goto:eof

:dirtree
setlocal
call set "pre=%%pre0:~-%~2%%
set /a ccount=%~3
set /a tcount=%~2+2
set /a dcount=0
set /a fcount=0
for /d %%i in (*) do set /a dcount+=1
echo( %pre%{
echo(  %pre%"type": "folder",
echo(  %pre%"name": "%~nx1",
set "fpath=%~f1"
set "fpath=%fpath:\=/%"
echo(  %pre%"path": "%fpath%",
echo(  %pre%"childno": %ccount%,

for %%i in (*) do set /a fcount+=1

if %fcount% gtr 0 (

    echo(  %pre%"files": [

    for %%i in (*) do (
        echo(  %pre%{"name": "%%i"}
        set /A fcount-=1
        if !fcount! gtr 0 (echo   %pre%,)
        )
    echo(  %pre%],
    )
)

if %dcount% equ 0 echo(  %pre%"subchilds": %dcount%
if %dcount% gtr 0 (
    echo(  %pre%"subchilds": %dcount%,
    echo(  %pre%"children": [
    for /d %%i in (*) do (
        for /f %%j in ('call echo "%%dcount%%"') do (
            cd "%%i"
            call:dirtree "%%i" "%tcount%" "%%j"
            cd ..
        )
        set /a dcount-=1
    )
    echo(  %pre%]
)

if %ccount% equ 1 (echo  %pre%}) else echo( %pre%},

endlocal
goto:eof
```

Seu resultado final será algo assim:

```
[
  {
   "type": "folder",
   "name": "libs",
   "path": "C:/teste/libs",
   "childno": 1,
   "files": [
       {"type":"file","name": "dir.txt"},
       {"type":"file","name": "tree2json.bat"}
   ],
   "subchilds": 5,
   "children": [
    {
     "type": "folder",
     "name": "bf",
     "path": "C:/teste/libs/bf/bf",
     "childno": 5,
     "files": [
         {"name": "authentication.js"},
         {"name": "item.js"},
         {"name": "menu.js"},
         {"name": "person.js"}
     ],
     "subchilds": 0
    },
[...]
```

Fonte: versão adaptada de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990113/cmd-tree-to-json
(A versão original lista apenas subdiretórios. A versão adaptada inclui também arquivos.)

Comment: eu sei que não tem como fazer a listagem de diretórios com javascript por isso eu já vou ter um json com os diretórios definidos como mostrei no meu **return**, o que eu preciso é que usando esse json eu gere algo como ["app/", "app/controllers/", "app/controllers/cad"]